# How to shuffle an array including the last element?

Tags: c++, arrays, random, vector, shuffle

I've tried using `std::random_shuffle` and `std::shuffle`, but they only shuffle the first and elements in between first and last, but not last. Is there a way to shuffle an array (vector) including the last element?

```
//NumberGenerator.h
#ifndef __NUMBERGENERATOR_H__
#define __NUMBERGENERATOR_H__
#pragma once
#include "Number.h" //regular numbers
#include "MegaNumber.h" //mega numbers
#include <vector> //<vector>
#include <string> //strings 
using std::to_string; //convert int to strings
#include <algorithm> //shuffle
//#include <random> //std::default_random_engine
#define NON_MEGA_COMBINATIONS 5
#define MEGA_COMBINATIONS 1

using std::vector; //<vectors>
using std::string; //string
using std::random_shuffle; //shuffles arrays

class NumberGenerator
{
public:
    NumberGenerator(vector<Number> numbers, vector<MegaNumber> megaNumbers); //constructor
    ~NumberGenerator();
    string pickNumbers(); //function that randomizes regularDraws and megaDraws
protected: 
    vector<Number> regularDraws; //contains number information
    vector<MegaNumber> megaDraws; //contains mega number information
};

#endif


//NumberGenerator.cpp
#include "NumberGenerator.h"


//constructor
NumberGenerator::NumberGenerator(vector<Number> numbers, vector<MegaNumber> megaNumbers)
{
    regularDraws = numbers;
    megaDraws = megaNumbers;
}

//destructor
NumberGenerator::~NumberGenerator()
{
}


string NumberGenerator::pickNumbers()
{
    srand(rand());
    random_shuffle(&regularDraws[1], &regularDraws[regularDraws.size() - 1]);
    random_shuffle(&megaDraws[1], &megaDraws[megaDraws.size() - 1]);
    string regular;
    string mega;
    string last = to_string(regularDraws[regularDraws.size() - 1].getID());

    for (int i = 1; i <= NON_MEGA_COMBINATIONS; i++)
    {
        regular = regular + " " + to_string(regularDraws[i].getID());
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= MEGA_COMBINATIONS; i++)
    {
        mega = mega + " " + to_string(megaDraws[i].getID());
    }

    return regular + " " + mega + " " + last;
}



//Number.h
#ifndef __NUMBER_H_
#define __NUMBER_H__
#pragma once


class Number
{
public:
    Number(int id); //constructor
    ~Number(); //destructor


    int getID(); //returns the number ID



protected:
    int ID; //This is the number 
};

#endif 

//Number.cpp
#include "Number.h"


//constructor
Number::Number(int id)
{
    occurence = 0;
    occurencePct = 0;
    ID = id;
}

//destructor
Number::~Number()
{
}

//returns the number ID
int Number::getID() 
{
    return ID; 
}


//MegaNumber.h
#ifndef __MEGANUMBER_H__
#define __MEGANUMBER_H__
#pragma once
#include "Number.h"

//Subclass of Number
class MegaNumber :
    public Number
{
public:
    MegaNumber(int id); //Will be inheriting Number superclass
    ~MegaNumber();
};

#endif

//MegaNumber.cpp
#include "MegaNumber.h"


//constructor
MegaNumber::MegaNumber(int id) : Number::Number(id) //inherits the super class Number
{

}

//destructor
MegaNumber::~MegaNumber()
{
}

//Source.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "NumberGenerator.h"
int main()
{
vector<Number> arg1 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
vector<MegaNumber> arg2 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 , 8, 9};
NumberGenerator game(arg1, arg2);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
      cout << game.pickNumbers() << endl;
  }
}
```

This is a slimmed down version of my code because it contains 10 files, I think it's enough to make sense though for what I'm doing. Anyhow, The last element doesn't get shuffled each time pickNumbers() is ran.

Comment: You're doing something wrong. Post code. `std::shuffle` as well `std::random_shuffle`, shuffle the range given, including the last element. Provided that last == one past the end.

Comment: Can you reduce the code to a [mcve], please? 99% of the stuff there's unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All standard library algorithms (and other functions) which take a pair of iterators operate on the half-open range `[first, last)`. However, that is no problem at all—all standard library containers are designed so that the iterator returned by `end()` (and variants) is a *past-the-end* iterator: it points to *one past the last real element in the container.* So this call:

```
std::vector<int> v = whatever();
std::random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end());
```

will actually shuffle *all* the `int`s in the vector.

In light of this, you can see you're using the function incorrectly. For the `last` argument, you're passing `&regularDraws[regularDraws.size() - 1]` (and similar)—the address of the last actual element in the vector. Since the interval is half-open, as I've outlined above, that last element is not part of the shuffle.

You shouldn't be using pointers into the vector at all<sup>(1)</sup>, but iterators instead:

```
random_shuffle(std::next(regularDraws.begin()), regularDraws.end());
```

The `std::next` is there because you were originally passing `[1]` (the second element in the vector) as the `first` argument, so I kept that (remember that array indexing is 0-based in C++). If that was not your intention, simply shuffle the entire vector:

```
random_shuffle(regularDraws.begin(), regularDraws.end());
```

---

Using half-open ranges everywhere is actually quite advantageous:

- It allows a simple expression of an empty range: `begin == end`
- All insertion points can be specified using an iterator, if we take that iterator to mean "before the element pointed to." `begin` then means "insert before the first element," and `end` translates to "insert before the one-past-last` element," i.e. "insert after the last element."
- It allows easy concatenation/splitting:

  ```
  auto b = rng.begin();
  auto e = rng.end();
  auto m = std::next(b, std::distance(b, e) / 2);
  processHalf(b, m);
  processHalf(m, e);
  ```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Your code only works because `std::vector` stores its elements contiguously in memory. With iterators, it will work with any container.

Comment: hmm.. but when I printf("%d", v[v.size() - 1]) I still get the same value even after being shuffled 10 times.

Comment: @TommySaechao Then there's probably a problem in your code, which you should post.

Comment: @TommySaechao Edited the answer.

Comment: That fixed it! Awesome! I'm curious, what if I wanted to start at element 12 instead of 1, how would I do that?

And can you elaborate more on iterators?

Comment: @TommySaechao `std::next(v.begin(), 12)`. And I am afraid SO is not the appropriate format for learning more on iterators, I suggest a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) for that.